# How to handle multiple PHP processes on multiple servers to only start when there is work, and sleep when there's nothing to do?

Tags: php, loops, queue, while-loop

I have a challenge I don't seem to get a good grip on.
I am working on an application that generates reports (big analysis from database but that's not relevant here). I have 3 identical scripts that I call "process scripts".

A user can select multiple variables to generate a report. If done, I need one of the three scripts to pick up the task and start generating the report. I use multiple servers so all three of them can work simultaneously. When there is too much work, a queue will start so the first "process script" to be ready can pick up the next and so on.

I don't want to have these scripts go to the database all the time, so I have a small file "thereiswork.txt". I want the three scripts to read the file and if there is something to do go do it. If not, do nothing.

At first, I just randomly let a "process script" to be chosen & they all have their own queue. However, I now see that in some cases 1 process script has a queue of hours while the other 2 are doing nothing. Just because they had the "luck" of not getting very big reports to generate so I need a more fair solutions to equally balance the work.

How can I do this? Have a queue multiple scripts can work on?

PS
I use set_time_limit(0); for these scripts and they all currently are in a while() loop, and sleep(5) all the time...

Comment: Do you have SSH access to this server, and the ability to use `exec()`?

Comment: Use Gearman.  Job Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task, I use the Gearman job server. Your PHP code sends out jobs and you have a background script running to pick them up. It comes down to a solution similar to symcbean's, but the dispatching does not require arbitrary sleeps. It waits for events instead and essentially wakes up exactly when needed.

It comes with an excellent PHP extension and is very well documented. Most examples are in PHP too, although it works transparently with other languages too.

http://gearman.org/

Comment: I start reading on gearman.org and looks like the best option to go so I'll make this as an answer. However, for anyone reading this... Also read the advice written by @symcbean . Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Looks like that was last updated over a year ago. I wonder if Celery would be more what you'd want, as it seems more well-supported: http://www.celeryproject.org/

Answer (score 2):

No, no, no.

PHP does not have the kind of sophisticated lock management facilities to support concurrent raw file access. Few languages do. That's not to say it's impossible to implement them (most easily with mutexes).

> I don't want to have these scripts go to the database all the time

DBMS provide great support for concurrent access. And while there is an overhead in perfroming an operation on the DB, it's very small in comparison to the amount of work which each request will generate. It's also a very convenient substrate for managing the queue of jobs.

> they all have their own queue

Why? using a shared queue on a first-come, first-served basis will ensure the best use of resources.

> At first, I just randomly let a "process script" to be chosen

This is only going to distribute work evenly with a very large number of jobs and a good random number generator. One approach is to shard data (e.g. instance 1 picks up jobs where mod(job_number, number_of_instances)=0, instance picks up jobs where mod(job_number, number_of_instances)=1....) - but even then it doesn't make best use of available resources.

> they all currently are in a while() loop, and sleep(5) all the time

No - this is wrong too.

It's inefficient to have the instances constantly polling an empty queue - so you implement a back-ofr plan, e.g.

```
$maxsleeptime=100;
$sleeptime=0;
while (true) {
   $next_job=get_available_job_from_db_queue();
   if (!$next_job) {
      $sleeptime=min($sleeptime*2, $maxsleeptime);
      sleep($sleeptime);
   } else {
      $sleeptime=0;
      process_job($next_job);
      mark_job_finished($next_job);
   }
}
```

No job is destined for a particular processor until that processor picks it up from the queue. By logging sleeptime (or start and end of processing) it's also a lot easier to see when you need to add more processor scripts - and if you handle the concurrency on the database, then you don't need to worry about configuring each script to know about the number of other scripts running - you can add and retired instances as required.

Comment: Wow, those are great tips and convincing arguments. Thanks, I'll take a look on how to get all your advice in! Thanks!